# highchart activity gauge chart using json data from a file

Tags: json, highcharts

I am new to using highcharts.js. I want to create an activity gauge chart using data from a json file or url. I have understood how they draw the chart but failed to understand the data format used in json to display the chart.
Here is my code

```js
    var options = {

            chart: {
                type: 'solidgauge',
                marginTop: 50
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Activity',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '24px'
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                backgroundColor: 'none',
                shadow: false,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '16px'
                },
                pointFormat: '{series.name}<br><span style="font-size:2em; color: {point.color}; font-weight: bold">{point.y}%</span>',
                positioner: function (labelWidth, labelHeight) {
                    return {
                        x: 200 - labelWidth / 2,
                        y: 180
                    };
                }
            },

            pane: {
                startAngle: 0,
                endAngle: 360,
                background: [{ // Track for Move
                    outerRadius: '112%',
                    innerRadius: '88%',
                    backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
                    borderWidth: 0
                }, { // Track for Exercise
                    outerRadius: '87%',
                    innerRadius: '63%',
                    backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
                    borderWidth: 0
                }, { // Track for Stand
                    outerRadius: '62%',
                    innerRadius: '38%',
                    backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
                    borderWidth: 0
                }]
            },

            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                lineWidth: 0,
                tickPositions: []
            },

            plotOptions: {
                solidgauge: {
                    borderWidth: '34px',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    linecap: 'round',
                    stickyTracking: false
                }
            },

            series: []
        };

    var gauge1;
    $.getJSON('bryan.json', function(json){
        console.log(json)
        options.chart.renderTo = 'container';
        options.series.data = json
        gauge1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
        /**
         * In the chart load callback, add icons on top of the circular shapes
         */
        function callback()
    {

        // Move icon
        this.renderer.path(['M', -8, 0, 'L', 8, 0, 'M', 0, -8, 'L', 8, 0, 0, 8])
            .attr({
                'stroke': '#ffffff',
                'stroke-linecap': 'round',
                'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
                'stroke-width': 2,
                'zIndex': 10
            })
            .translate(190, 26)
            .add(this.series[2].group);

        // Exercise icon
        this.renderer.path(['M', -8, 0, 'L', 8, 0, 'M', 0, -8, 'L', 8, 0, 0, 8, 'M', 8, -8, 'L', 16, 0, 8, 8])
            .attr({
                'stroke': '#ffffff',
                'stroke-linecap': 'round',
                'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
                'stroke-width': 2,
                'zIndex': 10
            })
            .translate(190, 61)
            .add(this.series[2].group);

        // Stand icon
        this.renderer.path(['M', 0, 8, 'L', 0, -8, 'M', -8, 0, 'L', 0, -8, 8, 0])
            .attr({
                'stroke': '#ffffff',
                'stroke-linecap': 'round',
                'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
                'stroke-width': 2,
                'zIndex': 10
            })
            .translate(190, 96)
            .add(this.series[2].group);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
</div>
```

And here is my json data which i thout might be rendered but it didnot.
[data.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBo6i.png)

Comment: Made a plunkr for anyone who wants to look at this: https://plnkr.co/edit/lyWQClG2nuPbtmkxg0lt , json data currently loads into 1 series, with 3 points. Tried 3 series with 1 point without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, instead of `options.series.data = json`, you need to create the first series and then populate its data array with your data. Also, set in each point different `radius` and `innerRadius` properties. Take a look at the example below.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.solidgauge.data.radius
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.solidgauge.data.innerRadius

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/x3cne1ng/

Comment: Thanks so much @d_paul for the solution..But still how do i change the series name from series 1 to name attribute in json file. And highcharts is also complicated for me when i try to create more activity gauges on the same page using different data but still from the same json file.

Comment: No problem. I placed all points in one series, so that is the reason why the series' name is not changed (they are points names). So if you want to split points into separate series, you need to modify JSON object a little. Here you can find an example with separate series: http://jsfiddle.net/g2evz0co/. As for the multiple charts, look at here: http://jsfiddle.net/z9m0cv81/. In case of any question, feel free to ask. Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Yeah. its really helpful. Actually i tried my best and i also came up with this [https://plnkr.co/edit/Pu0qNi959KlKOdr0ut1f?p=preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/Pu0qNi959KlKOdr0ut1f?p=preview). Though not fully to what i want which populates more gauges each representing its own data.  Thanks so much for ur help @d_paul